# MASM615 Procedure Re-Write not working (Want to add "USES" Directive)

Tags: assembly

I want to rewrite a procedure given to me in MASM615. I simply intend to use the "USES" directive so that i dont have to do all the pushes and pops to and from stack. This would clearly change some of the addresses referenced in the procedure, as they refer to the stack pointer (esp). I thought i implemented it properly, but the program hangs on me. The procedure is supposed to output a string that is written directly in the code stream, then skip over the string so that the CPU doesn't give error for trying to execute the string as code. below is the procedure i was GIVEN:

```
WritePrompt PROC
push ebp
mov ebp, esp           ; set up the ebp pointer
push esi               ; save used reg
push eax               ; save used reg
mov esi, [ebp+4]       ; use ret.addr. as string pointer 

L1:  cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 0  ; check for the end of string
jz L2                  ; jump if the string is over

mov al, [esi]          ; get the next string character
call WriteChar         ; ... and output it
inc esi                ; increment the string pointer
jmp L1

L2:  inc esi                ; adjust the string pointer
mov [ebp+4], esi       ; modify the return address

pop eax                ; restore all used regs and exit
pop esi
pop ebp
ret
WritePrompt ENDP
```

That was what i was given, and below is my simplified re-write, using the USES directive to skip stack pushes and pops:

```
outStr PROC USES eax ebp esi
mov ebp, esp
mov esi, [ebp]

L1:
cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 0
jz L2

mov al, [esi]
call WriteChar
inc esi
jmp L1

L2:
inc esi
mov [ebp], esi

ret
outStr ENDP
```

This procedure, when called, causes the program to hang. Why? what's wrong with it? I feel like i accounted for any changes that pushing and popping would have made.

Edit: after adding "call dumpregs" a few places for debugging, ive found that the line that crashes the program is "cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 0", which makes me think i havent gotten the pointer to the string properly from stack. using "mov esi, [ebp + 4]" seems to at least get me farther, but then it jumps to L2 right away.

Edit2:

I found the problem. It seems the documentation i am using is VERY unclear about what the USES directive does. It pushes all the "Used" registers to stack, and pops them after, just like would be done without the USES directive. Therefore, the commands i needed to use were:

```
mov ebp, esp
add ebp, 12
mov esi, [ebp]
```

Since i cant even answer my own questions yet, i guess i have to put it here. This question is closed. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

misunderstanding of "USES" Directive. Code was needed to compensate for registers pushed into stack.

```
mov ebp, esp
add ebp, 12
mov esi, [ebp]
```